# python error: Column names in each table must be unique. How to solve?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a code that reads and concatenates files with similar structure and sends it to the database. It works well except for this particular case.

part of the code I use is:

```
if file.suffix.lower() == '.xlsx' or file.suffix.upper() == '.XLSX':
     frame = pd.read_excel(file, header=0, engine='openpyxl')
(...)
     all_df_list.append(frame)


elif file.suffix.lower() == '.csv' or file.suffix.upper() == '.CSV':
     frameCSV = pd.read_csv(file, encoding="utf-8")
(..)
     all_df_list.append(frameCSV )

xls=pd.concat(all_df_list)
xls.to_sql(table, con=engine, if_exists='append', index=False, chunksize=10000)
```

This particular file raises this error:

```
(pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42S21', "[42S21] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Column names in each table must be unique. Column name 'Goal 09 - dp eur' in table 'custom_ga_goal_dpeur_carregosa' is specified more than once. (2705) (SQLExecDirectW)")

[SQL: 
CREATE TABLE dbo.custom_ga_goal_dpeur_carregosa (
    [Day] DATETIME NULL, 
    [Web Analytics Site Campaign] VARCHAR(max) NULL, 
    [Web Analytics Site Medium] VARCHAR(max) NULL, 
    [Web Analytics Site Source] VARCHAR(max) NULL, 
    [Web Analytics Site Content] VARCHAR(max) NULL, 
    [Web Analytics Keyword] VARCHAR(max) NULL, 
    [Device Category] VARCHAR(max) NULL, 
    [Goal 09 - dp eur ] FLOAT(53) NULL, 
    filename VARCHAR(max) NULL, 
    load_date VARCHAR(max) NULL, 
    [Goal 09 - dp eur] VARCHAR(max) NULL
)
```

I know what the error means. I just wonder if there is there any way I can solve this error through coding? Like if this happens, join the columns and take only one data type?
I can't just make a query for each case this happens because it's a lot of files and it might happen again with another file.

Comment: Have you tried looking at `df.columns` to see if you have duplicates?

Comment: Just convert all columns to strings before append command

Comment: Aside: `if file.suffix.lower() == '.xlsx' or file.suffix.upper() == '.XLSX':` You don't need to check both upper and lower. If one of them is true, so is the other.

Comment: That's not about about your error, but if you convert some string variable to lowercase and check if it is equal to some other word, then you don't need to use else one more checking by converting a string to uppercase :)

Answer (score 0):

Just convert all columns to strings before append command :

```
if file.suffix.lower() == '.xlsx':
     frame = pd.read_excel(file, header=0, engine='openpyxl')
     frame =frame.astype(str)
(...)
     all_df_list.append(frame)


elif file.suffix.lower() == '.csv':
     frameCSV = pd.read_csv(file, encoding="utf-8")
     frameCSV =frameCSV.astype(str)
(..)
     all_df_list.append(frameCSV )

xls=pd.concat(all_df_list)
xls.to_sql(table, con=engine, if_exists='append', index=False, chunksize=10000)
```

Comment: What does the error have to do with datatypes?

Comment: No error will be here pandas will handle the same column name with the same type and append the data. It will be varchar(max) whatever data you have

Comment: So it will combine the same-named columns from different tables when it merges them because they're the same dtype?

Comment: Yes exactly as you wrote

Comment: @LevGelman didn't work. Same error,

Comment: [SQL: 
CREATE TABLE dbo.custom_ga_goal_dpeur_carregosa (
 [Day] VARCHAR(max) NULL, 
 [Web Analytics Site Campaign] VARCHAR(max) NULL, 
 [Web Analytics Site Medium] VARCHAR(max) NULL, 
 [Web Analytics Site Source] VARCHAR(max) NULL, 
 [Web Analytics Site Content] VARCHAR(max) NULL, 
 [Web Analytics Keyword] VARCHAR(max) NULL, 
 [Device Category] VARCHAR(max) NULL, 
 [Goal 09 - dp eur ] VARCHAR(max) NULL, 
 filename VARCHAR(max) NULL, 
 load_date VARCHAR(max) NULL, 
 [Goal 09 - dp eur] VARCHAR(max) NULL
)

Comment: It did convert all data to string but it still assumes there are two columns named Goal 09 - dp eur

Comment: can you print (xls) before writing to database and see if you have two columns in dataframe with the same column?